# php SOAP object intermittent error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've got some code that creates a PHP SOAP Object. Most of the time I get the results back that I expect but sometimes I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in...
```

My code obviously works so I assume it's a server setting (max_execution_time??) but is it the webservice or on my client server?